# How to make UIPageViewController switch controllers automatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uipageviewcontroller

I was following this great tutorial from Duc Tran about UIPageViewController. I was wondering how would you make the controllers inside your UIPageViewController transition automatically without having the user swipe. This is how the code looks without the delegate and datasource.

```
class AnimesPageVC: UIPageViewController {
override var navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation {return .horizontal}

weak var pageViewControllerDelegate: AnimePagesVCDelegate?

var timeInterval: Int?

var images: [UIImage]?


lazy var animes: [UIViewController] = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var animes = [UIViewController]()

    if let images = self.images {
        for image in images {
            let anime = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnimeImage")

            animes.append(anime)
        }
    }
    self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.setUpPageController(numberOfPages: animes.count)

    return animes
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    delegate = self
    dataSource = self

    loadPage(atIndex: 0)
}

func loadPage(atIndex: Int) {
    let anime = animes[atIndex]
    var direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward
    if let currentAnime = viewControllers?.first {
        if let currentIndex = animes.index(of: currentAnime) {
            if currentIndex > atIndex {
                direction = .reverse
            }
        }
    }

    configurePages(viewController: anime)

    setViewControllers([anime], direction: direction, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func configurePages(viewController: UIViewController) {
    for (index, animeVC) in animes.enumerated() {
        if viewController === animeVC {
            if let anime = viewController as? AnimeVC {
                anime.image = self.images?[index]
                self.pageViewControllerDelegate?.turnPageController(to: index)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

So how would I be able to get that kind of behavior. Would appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to your view did load and call the same load function with updated index

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { (_) in
        // call your function here
        self.loadPage(atIndex: index + 1)
        // you have to update your index also.
        self.index = self.index + 1
    }
```

This will call your loadPage function each 0.3 sec

keep in mind that my solution is only for one way if you it's only going to next page because I am adding to automatically it will not come back to previous controller for that you have do something like

```
index = index - 1
```

Comment: Thanks Khalid, it work. However, it only works the first time. It switch from first controller to the second controller but doesn't switch to the next one. It also stays at the second controller, so if I try to swipe to the next or previous controller it goes back to the second controller.

Comment: because you have to update your index as well right now your index is 0 and you add 1. You have to keep your index also updated so it should work. I am editing the answer so you can see how